# Definition of static data member without repeating its type

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, one-definition-rule

When I have a class with a `static` `const` or `constexpr` data member, defining that variable reqires me to repeat stuff:

```
/// my_class.hpp
class my_class { constexpr static int x = 1; };
```

```
/// my_class.cpp
#include "my_class.hpp"
// auto my_class::x; // error: declaration of 'auto my_class::x' has no initializer
// decltype(auto) my_class::x; // error: declaration of 'decltype(auto) my_class::x' has no initializer
decltype(my_class::x) my_class::x; // ok
```

Of course I could do

```
#define DEFINE_STATIC_DATA_MEMBER(x) decltype(x) x
DEFINE_STATIC_DATA_MEMBER(my_class::x);
```

but I wonder if there’s a non-macro solution.

The question arose because both the type and the fully-qualified name of the static data member are lengthy and I’m likely to get more of these.

Comment: And even before C++17 `constexpr static` *must* be initialized in class and `const static` can be. Obfuscating code with macro will net you nothing. If you are tired of typing the names, maybe get an IDE with code completion?

Comment: Use less lengthy names.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You don't have to repeat anything. Since you already have initialized the member inside the class definition, you don't have to redefine it a second time. Anyway, use `const int` instead of `decltype(my_class::x)` (for the `const` scenario). [Demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/eqhTo3TK3)

Comment: @molbdnilo The problem isn’t `SimpleJavaLikeLenghtyNameAbstractFactoryImpl` lengthy names, but `std::template<std::tuple<std::variant<int, std::string>, std::nullptr_t, std::uint_fast16_t>` lenghty names. I whish I could make some of the sub-names shorter, but I cannot change library names, and changing class names results in a mega-diff.

Comment: @Fareanor, if the type in my code were `int`, I’d use `int`. I used `int` in my example because the actual type isn’t relevant to demonstrate the errors. Of course, the type in my production code is not `int` but some nested template instances. I’d rather use `decltype` than spelling out the type twice.

Comment: So use meaningful type aliases. Your example shows a lack of abstraction. (And mega-diffs are a fact of life when you've painted yourself into a corner and need to get out.)

Comment: You don't have to change class names in one huge commit. Add a name alias and new code can start using it, while you gradually refactor old code when you touch it.

Comment: If `decltype(my_class::x) my_class::x` is too long then your class `my_class` is a complicated template and then, yes, using a `using` or `typedef` is the tool of choice because you'll hate typing it out more than just here (and you don't want to have huge diffs just because you realize you need a uint32 as one of the inner template types instead of uint16!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from C++17 you don't need to separately define `static constexpr` variables.

Just `class my_class { constexpr static int x = 1; };` is enough, without a .cpp file.

Comment: Even before C++17. It is not allowed to declare a `static constexpr` member without an initializer.

Comment: I believe you, but anyway, as far as I know you can't have a separate definition for a `static constexpr` [as you can see here](https://godbolt.org/z/KG863xcvf) (C++11 example)

Comment: @Fareanor I think I misread your first comment. Now that I read it again, I don't understand what you mean, because I don't suggest keeping the variable uninitialized.

Comment: My comment was equivalent to replacing _"Starting from C++17 you don't need to separately define `static constexpr` variables."_ with _"You can't separately define `static constexpr` variables."_ :) Sorry if I was not clear :s

Comment: @Fareanor Gotcha. [You can](https://godbolt.org/z/Efnd1nb5G), but the initializer goes in the class body, not in the definition. In C++17 this separate definition is useless. Before, it's only needed if you ODR-use the variable (take its address, more or less).

Comment: Oh ! Alright, I completely missed that point. Thanks for the explanation !

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of a typedef to not have to repeat the type when defining it.

*my_class.hpp*

```
class my_class
{
    // Declaration
    static const my_very_lengthy_type_name_I_dont_want_to_repeat x;

    // typedef
    using t = decltype(x);
};
```

*my_class.cpp*

```
#include "my_class.hpp"

// Initialization
my_class::t my_class::x = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

> defining that variable requires me to repeat stuff:

For `static constexpr` data member, the above statement is true only for Pre-C++17 standard.

From C++17 onwards, we're allowed to omit writing an **out-of-class** definition of a `static constexpr` data member. This is illustrated in the example given below.

##### C++11

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static constexpr int OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE = -9999; //THIS IS A DECLARATION IN C++11 and C++14
    //other members here
};
```

In the above code snippet(which is for *C++11*,*C++14*), we have a **declaration** of the static data member `OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE` inside the class. And so, in **exactly one translation unit** we have to provide a corresponding **definition**. Otherwise you'll get a **linker error** which can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vMt1YCUejxqBY12g).

That is, in **exactly one** translation unit we should write:

```
constexpr int Foo::OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE;  //note no initializer
```

After adding the above out of class definition with [**no initializer**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Constant_static_members) the program will work. [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rj01yGYZe9yHLhqB)

#### C++17

But the out-of-class definition for `static constexpr` is no longer needed from C++17 onwards.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static constexpr int OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE = -9999; //THIS IS A DEFINITION IN C++17
    //other members here
};
```

In the above code snippet(which is for *C++17*) we have a **definition** of the static data member `OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE` inside the class. So since C++17, we don't have to provide the **definition** of `OUT_OF_BOUNDS_VALUE` anywhere else since we already have a definition for it inside the class and thus the same program [works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n9lG0g1U3QowAZFo) without any linker error.